# Are there any commoner mages?

Tags: alchemy-of-souls

In *Alchemy of Souls*, the talent to be a mage seems to be largely heritable, such that every child of a mage whom we have seen seems to also be a mage of some type. The mage families seem to also be, in essence, synonymous with nobility: they have hereditary wealth, influence in the court, royal recognition, and even some formal role in the government: for instance, Jinyowon can ignore royal orders in the pursuit of specific duties, and Songrim is empowered to investigate sorcery.

Almost all the mages that we have seen are explicitly from the "nobility" that run these institutions, or more minor families, such as Seo Yul. We know that Naksu's father was a court astrologer, and thus was also a mage, and from the scene where he was killed, appeared to live in a compound similar to those of the other noble families. Herb Gatherer Lee might live simply in the present, but he also seemed to have some rather lavishly appointed dwellings in the past.

As such, have we seen any mages who are explicitly common folk, in the sense that they are *not* from the noble families, major or minor?

Answer (score 1):

**Probably**

Near the end of the second part of the series, we are informed that Seo Yul is both in charge of selecting mages, *and* has made the unusual choice of looking beyond the prestigious families and assessing mages through open examinations. We then see two mages chosen through this new system whom "Jin Bu-Yeon" assessed for their potential, one of whose name is given as Sun-i (the other is unnamed).

The clear implication of all this is that there are mages, or people with the potential to be mages, outside the "nobility" represented by the official mage families.